# How to use a variable which is defined by m4_define macro in m4_esyscmd?

Tags: autoconf

I would like to do something similar with following code in `configure.ac`:

```
m4_define([product], [NGU29832])
m4_define([version], [R1A1])
```

After that use these variables in `AC_INIT` macro like this:

```
AC_INIT([foo], m4_esyscmd([$(pwd)/modify_version_script.sh $version $product]))
```

unfortunately, this doesn't work because `$version` and `$product` are both empty while parsed to `m4_esyscmd` macro.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution for this:

```
m4_define([product], [NGU29832])
m4_define([version], [R1A1])

AC_INIT([foo], m4_esyscmd([$(pwd)/modify_version_script.sh m4_defn([version] m4_defn([product])))
```

Answer (score 3):

`$version` and `$product` don't exist in the M4Sugar layer:  they are M4 variables:

```
m4_define([product], [NGU29832])
m4_define([version], [R1A1])

AC_INIT([foo], [m4_esyscmd([$(pwd)/modify_version_script.sh version product])])
```

Should work for you.